# Using Same Controller for Multiple View in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have to 2 folders in Views folder.

i.e  Foler1 and Folder2

I Created a Controller called CalController.cs, i want to use same controller for the .cshtml pages createded under the above 2 folders.

Can i get some suggestions to solve this issue.

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer on this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690910/mapping-asp-net-mvc3-controllers-to-views

Comment: Don't forget that in MVC, the URL that you type refers to a controller which calls the appropriate view.

Comment: I suggest partialviews or the usage of the 'Shared' folder

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend it, but this is how you would do it:

```
class CalController 
{
 public ActionResult Home()
 {
  return View("~/Views/Folder1/view.cshtml");
  //OR
  return View("~/Views/Folder2/view.cshtml");
 }
}
```

You could just put both views in the shared folder. I don't see why you to have your view in separate folders.